How to create a conversation dataset from a website without API?
I am currently doing my thesis on Natural Language Processing and it involves studying how people text online in a community so that it can be used to simulate conversational agents that can mimic real human conversations.
To this goal, I want to be able to create datasets containing strings of conversations for active forums or communities. Say for example https://www.ignboards.com/ or https://xdaforums.com/, is there any recommended way for doing so as I couldn't find any API for it.

You cannot work without an api of any website or forum let me clear that up with you cause this would what your entire process without an api would like like


Get the link of the website and use the requests and beautiful soup to webscrape the website for data.

You might be successful with the collecting the data but ur ip address would be flagged and the ip address would be blacklisted as
this is against privacy laws.

Even if u do pass the first two stages with a VPN the entire process is not worth to create a dataset and instead u could manually
copy paste and get more than this entire process.



Therefore in order for you to avoid using this Scenario i would like you to try this method

Understand your Requirements- how much data do you need to create a chatbot
Use API Such as stackoverflow or any other platform u would want to use with the given examples here

https://api.stackexchange.com/
https://www.twingly.com/forums-api/

Learn how to implement Specific API to work with your needs.

if u have any more issues in the process let me know ill help you out.
